# jbd2/dm-0-8 process consumes 100% I/O, makes system crash

Tags: ubuntu

I have an Ubuntu VM. For the third time in a month now, a process called `jbd2/dm-0-8` has been consuming 100% I/O and makes the system crash completely. MariaDB crashes and is unresponsive. I can't restart any services. I can, however, type in the shell and all. The only way to get the system up and running is by resetting the system (shutting the system down gracefully doesn't work, it won't respond to ACPI requests).

What is this process and how do I prevent the system from crashing? System used is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: any luck? im geting this too on cpanel systems

Comment: @AdamRamadhan Nope :(